# Saving a picture to a file in Skitch with one click?

Tags: skitch

Is there any way to press a single button in [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) and have it save the current image to a folder of your choosing (e.g. Documents). This is as opposed to using the drag and drop feature and having to open up finder and only then dropping the picture there.

I'm looking for something simple like the Save to history button on top.

Comment: Note to Googlers: the accepted answer is not the most useful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

There is no other single-click option besides saving (edited) pictures to the history.

[image]

You can however create an **Alias** of the Skitch folder `~/Pictures/Skitch` where the history is saved and drag it to a custom location.

[image]  → [image]

Comment: I notice the files there are saved as `.skitch` in that folder. Is there any way to get it to save as `.png`?

Comment: @Senseful Uh. You're right. That's annoying. I believe this is not possible. Skitch needs to save the edited pictures in a custom format to store information about your edits. Otherwise you would not be able to change them later.

Answer (score 6):

If you press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, it brings up an Export window where you can select the destination to export:

[image]

(I would suggest pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to switch to the Documents folder, but it seems this doesn't work in Skitch's Export window!)

Comment: You have to go through that dialog each time?

Comment: It seems so. Normally you can use keyboard shortcuts to make navigation easier, but they don't seem to work in Skitch. And Skitch doesn't look like it supports AppleScript, so there's no easy way to write your own solution.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out you can't save with one click. My solution is to create a folder specific to the project I'm working on which I place in the dock. Then I just drag the skitch tab to that folder. This way I can quickly create a few image variations and have them in one place ready for whatever's next. This method is handy too because you can very quickly set the image file type, drop it off and get back to manipulation.